# Must declare the scalar variable "@..."

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a website I'm developing and I am showing a GridView with a DetailsView when a row from the GridView is selected.  In the DetailsView I have an edit button that can enable the user to edit some information.  The error message is:

Must declare the scalar variable "@original_FirstName".

Here's the code:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"  
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices %>" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}"  
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM aspnet_Membership ORDER BY [Email], [LastName], [Company]" 
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE aspnet_Membership SET [FirstName] = @FirstName, [LastName] = @LastName, [Company] = @Company, [PartsList] = @PartsList, 
                  [UserName] = @UserName, [Question] = @Question, [Answer] = @Answer, [Role] = @Role, [Comment] =@Comment
                  WHERE [FirstName] = @original_FirstName AND [LastName] = @original_LastName AND [Company] = @original_Company AND
                  [PartsList] = @original_PartsList AND [UserName] = @original_UserName AND [Question] = @original_Question AND
                  [Answer] = @original_Answer AND [Role] = @original_Role AND [Comment] =@original_Comment"> 
        <UpdateParameters> 
            <asp:Parameter Name="FirstName" Type="String" /> 
            <asp:Parameter Name="LastName" Type="String" /> 
            <asp:Parameter Name="Company" Type="String" /> 
            <asp:Parameter Name="PartsList" Type="String" /> 
            <asp:Parameter Name="UserName" Type="String" /> 
            <asp:Parameter Name="Password" Type="String" /> 
            <asp:Parameter Name="Email" Type="String" /> 
            <asp:Parameter Name="Question" Type="String" /> 
            <asp:Parameter Name="Answer" Type="String" /> 
            <asp:Parameter Name="Role" Type="String" /> 
            <asp:Parameter Name="Comment" Type="String" />                    
        </UpdateParameters> 
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: I don't see that in your parameter list....

Comment: Do as you are being advised by the error message, declare that SQL parameter.

Comment: it's the first item in the WHERE clause @Daniel

Comment: @All pretending that the parameter is missing: The [OldValuesParameterFormatString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.oldvaluesparameterformatstring.aspx) should take care of the "missing" parameter - I never used it though and don't know why it wouldn't work here.